# Running ruby code

Tags: ruby

I am working on a remote server with Putty. My class looks like:

```
class Hangman
  def initialize
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end
```

But when I write in Putty `ruby hangman.rb`, it skips to the next editor console line without showing anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to actually *do* something; you're just defining a class.

Comment: Add `Hangman.new` at the end to see your message. Or in `irb` type `load "hangman.rb"` then you can try out your new class interactively

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hangman
  def initialize
    puts "Hello world"
   end
end

hangman = Hangman.new
```

So you forgot to crate an instance of the object you defined. Everytime you call .new method on your object, you get a new instance of it and code inside def initialize is ran.

Comment: added, but still nothing. My file is called hangman.rb and the class is called Hangman. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You define the class (with the constructor) but you don't use it. Create an object:

```
Hangman.new
```